# почему не срабатывает условие в C

Tags: c

Почему не срабатывает данное условие:

```
 if (key == hash)
        {
            printf("word: %s\n", key);
            return 0;
        }
```

Суть кода заключается в переборе всех кобинаций букв и печать слова которое подается при запуске при нахождении.

весь код указан здесь:

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <string.h>
char *key;

int combinations(int n, int t, string salt, string hash);

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (argc == 2)
    {
        eprintf("argc: %i\n", argc);
        char *salt = malloc(2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            salt[i] = argv[1][i];
        }
        salt[2] = '\0';
        key = malloc(5);
        combinations(2, 0, salt, argv[1]);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        eprintf("wrong number of arguments");
        return 1;
    }


}

int combinations(int n, int t, string salt, string hash)
{
    if (t == n)
    {
        if (key == hash)
        {
            printf("word: %s\n", key);
            return 0;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    for (char c = 'A'; c <= 'z'; c++)
    {
        key[t] = c;
        key[t+1] = '\0';
        combinations(n, t + 1, salt, hash);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Так же меня интересует как будет правильней написать условие, чтобы можно было выйти из рекрсивного цикла, чтобы при нахождении конкртеного слова не приходилось пробегать по остальным вариантам?

Comment: Используйте strcmp(), например

Comment: `string` это что в вашем случае? `char*`? Судя по `int main(int argc, string argv[])`?

Comment: @Sublihim посмотрите на [cs50.h](https://mirror.cs50.net/library50/c/cs50-library-c-3.0/cs50.h)

Comment: @jfs. Ну я о чем. Сравниваются не строки, а указатели

Answer (score 2):

Не будем лезть в алгоритм, пройдёмся только по основам C.

```
#include <cs50.h>
```

IMHO, нет никакого смысла использовать суррогаты, тем более маскирующиеся под C++, но совершенно с другими свойствами.

```
char *salt = malloc(2);
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    salt[i] = argv[1][i];
}
```

Зачем? Мы точно знаем сколько должно быть аргументов, поэтому:

```
char salt[3];
salt[0] = argv[1][0];
salt[1] = argv[1][1];
salt[2] = 0;
```

И не надо (забытых!) `free()`. Дальше,

```
salt[2] = '\0';
```

Влупили за границу выделеной памяти. Поэтому на предыдущем шаге - `[3]`, а не `[2]`.

```
key = malloc(5);
```

Ещё одно ненужное выделение памяти.

```
if (key == hash)
```

Вот не было бы маскировки под плюсовый `string` - было бы понятно, что нужно

```
if( !strcmp( key, hash ) )
```

так как в данном случае `string` - всего лишь алиас для `char *`. BTW, анализаторы кода на такое сравнение должны ругаться.

> как будет правильней написать условие, чтобы можно было выйти из рекрсивного цикла, чтобы при нахождении конкртеного слова не приходилось пробегать по остальным вариантам?

В алгоритме разбираться лень, но очевидно, что при срабатывании условия прекращения рекурсии нужно возвращать не 0, и после рекурсивного вызова проверять результат.

Comment: спасибо за советы!

Comment: А почему у нас здесь используется отрицание? "if( !strcmp( key, hash ) )"

Comment: @DmitryBakulin, [man strcmp](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?category=3&russian=&topic=strcmp).  Попробуйте сначала читать учебник по языку и справку по используемым функциям, потом писать код. Много нового узнаете, а уж сколько времени себе же сэкономите :)

Comment: в гайде man strcmp нет инфы про отрицание как и во многих других. Наткнулся на одном из ресурсов: http://beej.us/guide/bgc/output/html/multipage/strcmp.html
Получается что обычно возвращается 0, что может трактоваться как ложь? Поэтому и отрицание здесь?

Comment: *в гайде man strcmp нет инфы про отрицание* -- серьёзно? А это что? `RETURN VALUE The strcmp() and strncmp() functions return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if  s1 (or  the  first  n bytes thereof) is found, respectively, to be less than, to match, or be greater than s2.` *обычно возвращается 0* -- никакого "обычно" нет, что именно и в каких случаях возвращается расписано вполне однозначно. `if( !strcmp() )` - это просто проверка возвращаемого значения на 0, то де самое что и `strcmp() == 0` (тут снова слова про "читать учебник по C").

Comment: Спасибо, я понял